# Laravel Many-to-Many SQL Server Error

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

I'm hoping that I'm simply missing something, but I've spent a day trying to get this figured out on my own.

I'm working on trying to sync some `tags` to a `job`.

I've ran `dd()` to make sure when submitting the tags are submitting as an array, and I've made sure my relationships are properly hooked up in laravel.

However, when creating a new job with tags (no tags works fine because the insert doesn't actually happen), this error comes up:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
Incorrect syntax near ','. (SQL: insert into [ninja_job_tag] ([job_id], [tag_id]) 
values (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 10))
```

Here's the attach code (`$job` is properly created already):

```
$tagIDs = Input::get('tags') || [];
$job->tags()->attach(Input::get('tags'));
```

This is the function in `Job.php` to call the `tags`:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Marketing\Tag','ninja_job_tag');
}
```

This is the function in `Tag.php` to call the `jobs`:

```
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Marketing\Job','ninja_job_tag');
}
```

Here's the migration for the pivot table:

```
Schema::create('ninja_job_tag', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('ninja_jobs')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('ninja_tags')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Am I overlooking some stupid mistake? Thanks in advance for any help!

---

**UPDATE**

After some more investigating, adding only ONE tag works.  This led me to look in a different direction, and I found that in order to insert multiple rows in one statement, the database MUST be ran by SQL Server 2008 or newer.  It's unfortunate, but the server I need to run off of hasn't been updated in a long while and only runs SQL Server 2005 (version 9.0).

The only thing I can think of doing now is to use a `foreach` to loop through EVERY `tag_id` and attach them individually. Can anyone think of an alternate solution?

Comment: I don't know MS SQL Server Syntax enough to be sure but, I think  the insert statement generated by laravel is the problem. There are many value pairs for one insert. insert into [ninja_job_tag] ([job_id], [tag_id]) 
values (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 10); Could you try this statement in your MS SQL sql console? Did you configure laravel to produce for MS SQL?

Comment: Running that in plain SQL gives the same error. I narrowed it down to just ONE tag and it works fine. (`insert into [ninja_job_tag] ([job_id], [tag_id]) values (1, 1);`)

Comment: Ok, then that's the problem.  Lavarell produces the wrong sql. But sorry, today I heard of lavarell the first time. My only suggestion is that you configured a wrong dialect in Lavarell or it is simply a bug.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction @PeterPaulKiefer, it turns out it's because the server I need to use for the database is ran by SQL Server 2005, so there isn't support for inserting multiple rows in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is set up (as it should) to send an `insert` statement that will add multiple rows at once. The error comes up because the SQL Server version connected to is SQL Server 2005 (version 9.0), which **does not** support multiple rows in one `insert` statement.

If you're having this problem, you'll need to do one of two things:

1. Update your SQL Server to at least SQL Server 2008
2. Use a `foreach` to attach the relationship PER relation:

.

```
$tags = Input::get('tags');
foreach($tags as $tag){
    $job->tags()->attach($tag);
}
```

This is an unfortunate workaround since you'll be running an execute statement for each relation being created, but unless a custom override for `Eloquent` is created to use `UNION` in the attach statements, this will have to do.